# Multiple remote git repo in local directory with same directory structure

Tags: git, git-checkout

I'm learning more and more about git each day, so that leads to some inquiring questions.  I have two remote git repos each with their own structure, except both have an 'origin/dev'.  If I checkout using the following in each respective repo to my local:

Project1:

```
git checkout -b dev origin/dev
```

Project2:

```
git checkout -b dev origin/dev
```

Can I run into a scenario where I can have files from Project1 and Project2 in the same local 'dev' directory?  What is the best way around this?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are "Project1" and "Project2" separate directories? And where is the "dev" directory?

Answer (score 1):

Are these different projects on the two repos?  Then as long as you use a different folder for each project on your machine, then you should be fine.  You can verify this by going into each  folder on your machine and typing:

```
    git remote -v
```

As long as the url for `origin` matches the project you're in, you are fine.

If it's two different repos for the same project, then you cannot have 2 `origin` remotes.  You can have one remote called `origin`, but the other remote repo would have to be called something else.

```
    origin/dev
    <other_remote>/dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you can have two different names for the remotes as @triad pointed out you would never have files from both remote branches merged without doing it explicitly.

If you want to have them merged you have many options, two of them would be:

```
// Option 1
git checkout -b dev origin/dev
git merge other_remote/dev
// solve possible merge conflicts
git push // this will push into origin/dev

// Option 2
git checkout -b dev other_remote/dev
git merge origin/dev
// solve possible merge conflicts
git push // this will push into other_remote/dev
```

It's important also to realize that using

```
git checkout -b dev origin/dev
// or
git checkout --track origin/dev
```

... you are making dev local branch track dev remote branch. This can led to a lot of confusion in your scenario if you run git push or git pull without explicitly mention the remote branches you want to push or pull.